# Looking for a word that describes a place or experience that means something different to every individual

Tags: single-word-requests

A word that describes a place or experience that means something different to every individual.

Think along the lines of how "rite of passage" and "landmark" are used.

An example would be if someone said something like, "You never went to blockbuster when you were a kid? That place was a ______! How could you have never gone!"

Comment: It's actually '_rite_ of passage', meaning a ritual that marks a new stage in a person's life.

Comment: I don't see any connection between the first sentence's "means something different to every individual" and landmarks, rite of passage, and special qualities of Blockbuster stores. Nor can I connect landmarks and rites of passage to the way the speaker in the third sentence feels about Blockbuster stores.

Answer (score 2):

- That place was a ***legend***!
- That place was a **tradition**!

Answer (score 1):

While the word is more commonly used to describe a person, ***icon*** can also apply to an object, building, etc (in the "rite of passage" / "landmark" sense you're looking for), hence the adjective *iconic*. Your sentence would therefore be:

> "You never went to Blockbuster when you were a kid? That place was
>   **iconic**! How could you have never gone!"

or

> "You never went to Blockbuster when you were a kid? That place was an
>   **icon**! How could you have never gone!"

The definition:

> ### [icon](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/icon)
>
> 2. A person or thing regarded as a representative symbol or as worthy of veneration.
>
>    - *‘The car is a two-faced modern symbol: a shiny icon of our freedom
>        and our entrapment.’*

Answer (score 1):

I'm having difficulty connecting the request with the example. But anyway, using the example, you could use the metaphor "cornerstone" and say "That place was a *cornerstone of my childhood*!"